# How to get application/pdf media type from Jersey 2.X

Tags: java, rest, web-services, pdf, jersey

I am using `Jersey`for the services I am consuming. One of my services is returning `application/pdf` and I have a method which basically looks for the compatible media type and returns true if it is compatible. I am using `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE` to support pdf but it is not working. `response.getMediaType()` gives me `application/pdf` but there is no such media type in MediaType class.

Not sure how to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer. I used MediaType.WildCard_Type and it is working.

Thanks.

Comment: MediaType.WildCard_Type is not accessible to me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I've had the same problem, but I've made 'my own' MediaType which helped me. Maybe it helps others as well.

```
public static final MediaType APPLICATION_PDF_TYPE = new MediaType("application", "pdf");
```

Then I could use the type, in my case I used it to compare the parameter my method received `(MediaType mediaType)` and used `mediaType.isCompatible(APPLICATION_PDF_TYPE);` with it.